# JQuery Vertical Carousel endless scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having a minor issue with a vertical scrolling carousel. I am using JQuery, HTML and CSS for this project. The idea is to make it scroll endlessly in a vertical motion, it works fine, however on the first transition it trips from the last child to the second instead of transitioning from the last to the first, it works properly after the first transition.

Here is the code and the fiddle at the end:

The HTML:

```
<div id='carousel_container'>
 <div id='carousel_inner'>
  <ul id='carousel_ul'>
   <li><a href='#'><img src='http://e-home.mx/html5/img/carousel_1.png' /></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><img src='http://e-home.mx/html5/img/carousel_2.png' /></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><img src='http://e-home.mx/html5/img/carousel_3.png' /></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><img src='http://e-home.mx/html5/img/carousel_4.png' /></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><img src='http://e-home.mx/html5/img/carousel_5.png' /></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><img src='http://e-home.mx/html5/img/carousel_6.png' /></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><img src='http://e-home.mx/html5/img/carousel_7.png' /></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#carousel_container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:26px;
    right:0;
}
#carousel_inner {
    width:210px;
    height:120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
#carousel_ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    height:1000px;
    width:210px;
}
#carousel_ul li {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 110px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
#carousel_ul li img {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    border: 0px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
}
```

The JQuery / JS:

```
var car_ul = $('#carousel_ul');
car_ul.find('li').first().before(car_ul.find('li').last());

function scroll_down() {
    $('#carousel_ul:not(:animated)').animate({
        'top': parseInt(car_ul.css('top')) - car_ul.find('li').outerHeight() - 10
    }, 500, function () {
        var cars = car_ul.find('li');
        car_ul.css({
            'top': '-120px'
        });
        cars.last().after(cars.first());
    });
}

var interval_id = setInterval(function () {
    scroll_down();
}, 5000);
```

And lastly the [link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CSfLD/70/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by editing the javascript / JQuery to this:

```
var car_ul = $('#carousel_ul');
function scroll_down(){
 $('#carousel_ul:not(:animated)').animate({'top' : parseInt(car_ul.css('top')) - car_ul.find('li').outerHeight() - 10},500,function(){
  var cars = car_ul.find('li');
  cars.last().before(cars.first());
  car_ul.css({'top' : '0px'});
 });
}
var interval_id = setInterval(function(){scroll_down();},5000);
```

Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

```
car_ul.css({
        'top': '+=120px'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit this line on your code as it was missing the Radix parameter

```
'top': parseInt((car_ul.css('top')) - car_ul.find('li').outerHeight() - 10,10)
```